# Find a Maven Dependency or Repo from an Import Statement in Java Code

Tags: java, maven

Is there a nice easy way to find out the Maven  information for a library specified in an import statement in Java code?

For example, if I see some random piece of Java code on the internet that looks useful (happens often!), and I want to copy it into a Maven project, how do I find out what that dependency information is (i.e. the groupId, artifactId and version) to place into the POM.xml file?

e.g. If I see this:

```
import wow.magiclibrary.net.*;

public class Magic
{
  public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException 
  {
    try 
    {    
      MagicLibrary ml = new MagicLibrary( args[0] );

      ml.doSomethingAmazing();

...
```

... where can I find the information to put into the POM.xml file to make Maven download the `wow.magiclibrary.net` library as a dependency from whatever repository it comes from?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>wow.magiclibrary.net</groupId>
    <artifactId>magiclibrary</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Do I just have to use Google to search for a repo on the web that has the library, download jars manually and install them into my local maven repo?

Just curious.  I'm lazy.  I know I can do something like this after downloading a jar file:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=wow.magiclibrary -DartifactId=magiclibrary \
     -Dversion=2.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=magiclibrary2.0.0.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

... but if there was a way to automate the search and install process through Maven then that would rock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I'm looking for the maven dependency for a library I know usually go to

http://mvnrepository.com/

If I'm looking for a library I don't know, I would first do a simple google search or [grepcode.com](http://www.grepcode.com) and then go to mvnrepository.com

mvnrepository allows you to easily copy paste the maven dependency, here is an example for commons.lang version 2.6

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6

Comment: Another great source to search for artifacts is http://search.maven.org/. It provides much more detailed (and better presented) information on them. Check out [this page](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.avro%7Cavro%7C1.7.7%7Cbundle) for some example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use online tools like [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com), which will identify you the jar names and maven artifacts. Here is an example for [apache commons-lang StringUtils](http://grepcode.com/search/?start=0&query=StringUtils&entity=type).

Comment: Yesssss... that's what I wanted.  Cheers

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found the answer was what you needed, consider marking it as accepted as described in this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work